# Recursive computation of Nth derivative leads at divergence after 3 iterations

Tags: python, math, derivative

I am applying the formal definition of the derivative which works fine when it's the first order

```
h = 1e-05 #Some number ultimately close to 0
def derivative(f,x):
    return (f(x+h) - f(x)) / h #The formal definition
```

But when generalizing the formula for the **Nth** order it strangely diverges for some reason at 3 iterations

```
from functools import lru_cache #For handling recursion

@lru_cache(maxsize=200)
def NthDerivative(f,x,n):
    if n==1:
        return derivative(f,x)
    return ( NthDerivative(f,x+h,n-1) - NthDerivative(f,x,n-1) ) / h

for i in range(1,100):
   print(NthDerivative(lambda x : x**5,1,i))
```

This works totally fine until the iterations go above 3

```
5.000100001040231 #1st order
20.00059895479467 #2nd order
60.17408793468348 #3rd order
-44408.92098500626 #4th order (Here it happens)
11102230246.251564
-2220446049250312.5
3.5527136788004995e+20
-4.440892098500624e+25
```

I can't understand what going wrong here, is it because of some small floating number error?
Of course this does not only happen at this specific function, eveything I tried diverges at the same point at **3**.

What's wrong here?

Comment: If you use a debugger, where does it *first* diverge from what is expected?

Comment: What is the 4th derivative of x**5? You can work it out analytically, to check your results.

Comment: Works fine for a bigger `h`.

Comment: You are running into a catastrophic [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) due to subtracting almost equal numbers. This is more of a numerical analysis question than a programming question.

Comment: Using a higher `h` at 4th iterations seems to give more accurate results

Answer (score 0):

```py
h = 1e-05 #Some number ultimately close to 0
def derivative(f,x):
    return (f(x+h) - f(x)) / h #The formal definition
```

A small vocabulary issue: this is **not** the formal definition of a derivative. It is an approximation formula.

### Using a symmetric approximation formula instead of an asymmetric one

Using a more symmetric formula gives much better results on most functions:

```py
h = 1e-05 #Some number ultimately close to 0
def derivative(f,x):
    return (f(x+h) - f(x-h)) / (2*h) #A better approximation
```

Using the same logic, you can modify your Nth derivative code:

```py
def NthDerivative(f,x,n):
    if n==1:
        return derivative(f,x)
    return ( NthDerivative(f,x+h,n-1) - NthDerivative(f,x-h,n-1) ) / (2*h)
```

Or the other way around:

```py
def NthDerivative(f,x,n):
    if n==0:
        return f(x)
    else:
        return NthDerivative(lambda y: derivative(f,y), x, n-1)
```

I can't reproduce your diverging results, because I don't know which functions you were trying to differentiate.

### Directly writing the formula for higher-order derivatives

Instead of using recursion to approximate *the derivative of the approximation of the derivative of the approximation of the...* you could write an approximation formula for a higher-order derivative directly.

For instance, writing `f'(x) = (f(x+h) - f(x-h)) / (2*h)` and `f''(x) = (f'(x+h) - f'(x-h)) / (2*h)` and developing the occurrences of `f'(y)` in `f''(x)`, you will get:

```
f''(x) = (f(x+2*h) - 2 * f(x) + f(x-2*h)) / (4 * h**2)
```

Writing out the formula in this way is more efficient than calling the recursive function, as it results in one fewer evaluation of `f`.

Similar formulae can be obtained for `f'''`, `f''''`, etc.

Finally, you could try to find the **general** formula for the Nth derivative.

Comment: Testing it with **polynomial** functions it diverges at around the same iterations. Since `h` and `2*h` are almost the same number it does not cause much difference.  Periodic functions like `sin` also seem to diverge at the same iterations.

Comment: @Countour-Integral There is a factor 2 between `h` and `2*h`. Those are two different numbers.